# Fourier coefficients, Fourier spectrum and signal energy

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I was wondering if the equation 1) is correct in this example. The author described the difference between equations for $X(w)$ and $X[k]$. The only difference I see is the $\frac{1}{T}$ coefficient. Thus I can't see where $w$ comes from in eq. 1) denominator, or small $t$ in its middle part. Shouldn't it be a big $T$?

Now assuming that indeed ${|X[k]|}^2$ equals the energy contained at that frequency of periodic signal. How could we use the relation between equations for $X(w)$ and $X[k]$ to derive eq. 2)?
I'm not sure how we know that ${|X[w]|}^2$ represents density of a non-periodic signal. Isn't it just equal to energy contained at frequency $w$ multiplied by $T^{2}$, where $T \to \infty$?

[image]

Source: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3_tex.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is really confusing. It took a while for me to understand. But he is talking about *units* in 1).

So [XX] refers to the unit of XX.

Essentially he is saying, the unit of the continuous spectrum (X[w]) is the unit of the discrete spectrum (X[k]) times the unit of time ([t]), or divided by the unit of frequency ([w]). That is a rather obvious statement, and has nothing to do with 2).

So 1) and 2) are in my opinion totally unrelated. Probably this is where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: Any idea where 2) comes from, knowing that ${|X[k]|}^2$ equals signal energy at k-th frequency? The equation just appears there with no justification.

Comment: There is no formal mathematical derivation of 2), so formally it is a definition. You can motivate it from the unit (i.e. |X(w)|^2 is energy per frequency) and the fact that the total signal energy is obtained by integrating over -inf .. inf (This is the Plancherel theorem). I dont see any benefit from relating it to |X(k)|^2 - maybe just that it looks similar.

Comment: Thanks. Just making sure - in eq.1) X(w) is not equal to X[k] * w, but it's just about the difference in units of X(w) and X[k]? Secondly, is there any easy explanation of why we are squaring X[k] or X(w) in the energy formula?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Hmm, I think of it as X(w) being kind an "amplitude" so X(w)^2 is a "power/energy".

Comment: You mentioned Plancherel theorem - didn't you mean Parseval's theorem? (quote: The interpretation of this form of the theorem is that the total energy contained in a waveform x(t) summed across all of time t is equal to the total energy of the waveform's Fourier Transform X(f) summed across all of its frequency components f.)

Comment: In principle, yes. The Plancherel theorem is more general than Parsevals. But for the purpose here there is practically no difference.